# Analytical badge still alive?

Tags: support, badges, analytical-badge

The badge “Analytical” says “Visited every section of the FAQ (retired)”. This sounds like nobody can get this badge anymore, but, still, there are some people who earned it recently:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1306/analytical

How did they do that?